# Is it OK if Flutter app in Xcode's archive is named Runner?

Tags: flutter

After following the instructions on https://flutter.dev/docs/deployment/ios I came to the point, where I create app archive in Xcode (Xcode: Product > Archive). My app in archive is named `Runner`, although this is not its name.

Is this expected in Flutter or should app in archive be named according to its Display Name?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It is expected, nothing to worry about, just like when you build the release version for Android, you get the apk file name as `app-releases.apk`, similarly you get `Runner.ipa` for iOS and it doesn't mean your app named got changed. It is there in the bundle.

So, you are good and everything is OK.